# Apex Trigger count the number of updated records

Tags: trigger

I want to create a trigger on Opportunity object. I want to print the opportunity records which were updated along with the old value and new value both.

Also  I want to print  how many records' names have been changed.

I have a problem of the second part .It always gives me 1?
How can I figure this out?
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you paste the code you have written so far to help troubleshoot your issues?

Comment: Please include any code or error messages always as ***text***. Images are extremely poor for accessibility, search, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using maps

```
for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
  if (Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Name != o.Name) { // name changed
     count++;
  }
}
```

Maps are way more efficient than doing for loops inside of for loops, especially as the transaction could be of size 200